# why do I see the output of error_log but not die in PHP?

Tags: php

I noticed that when I issue a *die* statement in php, it's output doesn't appear on the error log (If i put an error_log statement right beside it it shows fine though).

I tried everything.. Here are the settings I did to make sure I see all my error logs:

**php.ini**:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
error_log = /Applications/XAMPP/logs/error_log
```

**httpd.conf:**

```
php_value error_log /Applications/XAMPP/logs/error_log
```

i even set up an **.htaccess** file in the root directory of one of my virtual hosts:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log /Applications/XAMPP/logs/error_log
```

but then every time I reach a statement like this in the code:
die("I love Prestashop");

the code just dies without any output..  any ideas guys?

I got the site running on my localhost using XAMPP and I'm running a Prestashop website, with PHP 5.3.1

Comment: `die()` does not place anything in the error log. It just dies the script (ends it), see http://php.net/die

Comment: use a set_error_handler or trigger_error()

Comment: and so if you have something like this:
die ("something went wrong here and that something is $variable") where do I see that statement? on the browser? on an error_log file?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I would love to use trigger_error().. thing is I'm installing a module ontop of Prestashop (an e-commerce framework) and I would like to be able to view their die statements which give useful debugging info, rather than tracing my way down which is time consuming

Comment: @abbood: Register yourself a shutdown function and buffer all output. in your shutdown function you can retrieve the whole output, including the one from die() then. And if it is like you describe, then Prestashop doesn't look like a good software. File a bug report and tell them that these `die()`s make things hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `die()` should not produce output in the `error_log` as calling it is **not** an error.

It is just a PHP construct (alias to `exit()`) that exits the current script and sends (optional) output (or an error code that is useful when used in a CLI environment).

Comment: and so if you have something like this:
die ("something went wrong here and that something is $variable") where do I see that statement?

Comment: @abbood In the output of your program.

Answer (score 0):

die() or exit() is not useful for reporting errors. They cannot be caught and cannot be logged. Use trigger_error() instead.